# How to restrict from user to be able to click on activity before clicking on dialog on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

So i have one simple dialog thats starts when activity is created, but when i click besides the dialog it is closed and activity is shown. I would like to disable the activity until the user click the button on dialog box. Can you give me some ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please have a look of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please set this-

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```